# Select directory from a file

Tags: windows, powershell

I need my program to give me every folder containing files which are out of the Windows' number of characters limit. It means if a file has more than 260 characters (248 for folders), I need it to write the address of the file's parent. And I need it to write it only once. For now, I'm using this code:

```
$maxLength = 248

Get-ChildItem $newPath -Recurse |
    Where-Object { ($_.FullName.Length -gt $maxLength) } |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName |
    Split-Path $_.FullName
```

But the `Split-Path` won't work (this is the first time I use it). It tells me the `-Path` parameter has a null value (I can write `-Path` but it doesn't change anything).

If you want an example of what I need: imagine `folder3` has a 230-character address and `file.txt` has a 280-character address:

```
C:\users\folder1\folder2\folder3\file.txt
```

Would write:

```
C:\users\folder1\folder2\folder3
```

I'm using PS2, by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Spoiler:** the tool you are building may not be able to report paths over the limit since `Get-ChildItem` cannot access them. You can *try* nevertheless, and also find other solutions in the links at the bottom.

**Issue in your code:** `$_` only works in specific contexts, for example a `ForEach-Object` loop.

But here, at the end of the pipeline, you're only left with a string containing the full path (not the complete file object any more), so directly passing it to `Split-Path` should work:

```
$maxLength = 248

Get-ChildItem $newPath -Recurse |
    Where-Object { ($_.FullName.Length -gt $maxLength) } |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName |
    Split-Path
```

as `"C:\Windows\System32\regedt32.exe" | Split-Path` would output `C:\Windows\System32`

**Sidenote:** what do `(Get-Item C:\Windows\System32\regedt32.exe).DirectoryName` and `(Get-Item C:\Windows\System32\regedt32.exe).Directory.FullName` output on your computer ? These both show the directory on my system.

**Adapted code example:**

```
$maxLength = 248

Get-ChildItem $newPath -Recurse |
    Where-Object { ($_.FullName.Length -gt $maxLength) } |
    ForEach-Object { $_.Directory.FullName } |
    Select-Object -Unique
```

**Additional information about `MAX_PATH`:**

[How do I find files with a path length greater than 260 characters in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12697259/how-do-i-find-files-with-a-path-length-greater-than-260-characters-in-windows)

[Why does the 260 character path length limit exist in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880321/why-does-the-260-character-path-length-limit-exist-in-windows)

http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2012/07/24/jaap-brassers-favorite-powershell-tips-and-tricks/

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-ChildItemV2-to-list-29291aae

Comment: I didnt try Directory.fullName but DirectoryName only works with PS3. How do you want me to test Directory.fullName in my program ? I do have troubles with pipelines

Comment: I have added another snippet to my answer

Comment: Okay, it works, and it is faster ! The last step is the condition, but it wont be a problem. Thanks for your help !
Edit : Erm we didnt solve the "unique" problem, the file mustn't contain 2 times the same folder.

Comment: Pipe the list to `Select-Object -Unique` :-) (last example updated to reflect this).

Comment: Here is another recent tool to address the overlength path issue : https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-ChildItemV2-to-list-29291aae

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use `get-childitem` to list paths greater than the windows character limit.

There are a couple of alternatives for you. Try an external library like '[Alphafs](https://github.com/alphaleonis/AlphaFS)'  or you can use robocopy. Boe Prox has a script that utilizes robocopy and it is available on [technet](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-Deeply-Nested-Files-a2148fd7) but i am not sure if it will work on PSV2. Anyway you can give it a try.

Comment: Well actually it seems like the program is working, the only problem is that lots of folders are written many times

Comment: By `program` do you mean the technet script that i linked? if so just use the `select-object -unique` like @sodawillow suggested..

Comment: I mean the `get-childitem`, now i'm waiting to see if the `select-object -unique` is going to work

Comment: `get-childitem` will most certainly not work with paths more than 260 characters...but if it working for you then all i can say is great :)...i am off now..good luck.

Answer (score -1):

I've had a similar problem and resolved it like this:

```
$PathTooLong = @()

Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $Path -Recurse -ErrorVariable +e -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$e | where {$_.Exception -like 'System.IO.PathTooLongException*'} | ForEach-Object {
    $PathTooLong += $_.TargetObject
    $Global:Error.Remove($_)
}

$PathTooLong
```

On every path that is too long, or that the PowerShell engine can't handle, `Get-ChildItem` will throw an error. This error is saved in the `ErrorVariable` called `e` in the example above.

When all errors are collected in `$e` you can filter out the ones you need by checking the error `Exception` for the string `System.IO.PathTooLongException`.

Hope it helps you out.