# azure/webapps-deploy@v2 GitHub Action keeps failing with long path error, but I'm using Ubuntu

Tags: windows, azure, ubuntu, github, github-actions

So I have a workflow that contains the action mentioned in the title. It runs on Ubuntu (`runs-on: ubuntu-latest`), and I'm getting a long path error:

```
The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
Error: Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
Error: Deployment Failed with Error: Package deployment using ZIP Deploy failed. Refer logs for more details.
```

I don't understand this, because this is a Windows error, but I'm running it on Linux.

Any idea why could this happen? Also, how could I check which path is too long? Is there any option to `echo` the path that is too long?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
I locally searched for long paths with a PS script: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41728153/16192320

I found out that all of the long paths are caused by deeply nested `node_modules` folders, so in the GitHub workflow I ran a command line script to delete those folders. (They weren't needed for deployment.)